# How map.find() works looking at the outputted assembly

Tags: c++, dictionary, assembly, std, libc++

I was debugging a crash on an Android application and came across the following lines:

```
void myobject::save(std::string toSave) {
...
}
...
std::map<std::string, std::string> dict;
...    
myobject::save(dict.find("username")->second);
```

The resulting assembly:

```
02F05DFC               bl         _ZNKSt6__ndk16__treeINS_12__value_typeINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEES7_EENS_19__map_value_compareIS7_S8_NS_4lessIS7_EELb1EEENS5_IS8_EEE4findIS7_EENS_21__tree_const_iteratorIS8_PNS_11__tree_nodeIS8_PvEEiEERKT_
3096                   str        r6, [sp, #0x108 + var_48]
0146                   mov        r1, r0
CDE92E66               strd       r6, r6, [sp, #0x108 + var_50]
11F81C2F               ldrb       r2, [r1, #0x1c]!
12F0010F               tst.w      r2, #0x1
06D1                   bne        loc_THERE

                  loc_FIRST:
D1E90002               ldrd       r0, r2, [r1]
8968                   ldr        r1, [r1, #0x8]
3091                   str        r1, [sp, #0x108 + var_48]
CDE92E02               strd       r0, r2, [sp, #0x108 + var_50]
04E0                   b          loc_HERE

                  loc_THERE:
D0E90821               ldrd       r2, r1, [r0, #0x20]
2EA8                   add        r0, sp, #0xb8_ZNSt6__ndk112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEPKcj
FDF743FD               bl         _ZNSt6__ndk112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEPKcj

                  loc_HERE:
2EA9                   add        r1, sp, #0xb8
2046                   mov        r0, r4
04F047FB               bl         _ZN6myobject11saveENSt6__ndk112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE
```

I found out the error. The crash happens when the find() return an end() iterator. But, interestingly, the crash occurred inside new() (which is done inside basic_string::__init() ). When find() return an end() iterator, it seems that the dereference of end() (end()->second) does not crash but it crash when it convert the end()->second into a std::string() right before passing it to myobject::save().

I tried to look into the libcxx implementation but did not found what I was looking for. Does anyone know what is the purpose of the two blocks loc_FIRST and loc_THERE? Why does it check *(r1+0x1c) == 0x1? And can someone explain me where the "->second" occurred in the assembly code?

Comment: Pro Tip: On any function that returns an iterator and it could be the `end` iterator always check the return against `end` before you use it,

Comment: `end()->second` exhibits undefined behavior. The exact failure mode of a program exhibiting undefined behavior is not really that interesting. Why do you care? But if you insist: `end()` is effectively a pointer to garbage. That garbage is then passed to `std::string` copy constructor, since `save()` takes its argument by value. The copy constructor tries to actually use the contents of that garbage, and crashes.

Comment: `c++filt` just set a new record for most unreadable expansion of a mangled symbol name: `std::__ndk1::__tree_const_iterator<std::__ndk1::__value_type<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > >, std::__ndk1::__tree_node<std::__ndk1::__value_type<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>,  ...` stopped there because it was too long for one comment by another 1000 characters!

Comment: (That's from the first `bl` instructions, which returns a pointer to some kind of object which has a member at `+0x1c` that your code is checking the low bit of.  Note it's a `tst`, not `cmp`, so the result depends only on the low bit of the byte loaded by `ldrb`, not the whole thing).

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik You are right, I should not care about it and simply check against end() before using it (that's what I did actually). But I'm curious about how C++ was lowered in assembly code. More precisely the two blocks loc_FIRST and loc_THERE above. The C++ code seems to add a condition that sometimes use the copy constructor and sometimes don't based on the *(r1+0x1c) value. I really would like to understand what is the purpose of that piece of "magic" code.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I understand **what** the code does but not **why** it does that (what is the member at +0x1C? The ->second? If yes, why checking the low bit?). In fact, the C++ line is only `myobject::save(dict.find("username")->second)` and does not contain any condition. The first `bl` is the find() function, the second one is the basic_string.__init(char*, int).

Comment: Are you sure about that?  It looks like it partially inlined.  You *might* get something useful out of a disassembly that annotates each asm with corresponding C++ source lines (like the color coding on http://gcc.godbolt.org/, or [`objdump -SrwC`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950799/source-interleaved-disassembly-from-gdb-and-objdump)).  Anyway, you didn't *quite* get the "what" correct: it's  `*(r1+0x1c) & 1 == 0`.  Not `*(r1+0x1c) == 0x1`.  I don't happen to know off the top of my head what libc++ or libstdc++ do internally to implement `std::map::find()`

Comment: I think it's doing a small string optimization (SSO). The `loc_FIRST` case would be the case where the string is contained in the SSO buffer, and just copies the 12 bytes of the string directly into the stack location for the string. The `loc_THERE` case is when SSO is inactive and calls `std::string::__init` to do the allocation and other non-SSO init work. So essentially that branch is part of the `std::string` construction which has been inlined into this code (but the slow non-SSO path is still out of line). The bit being checked presumably indicates whether SSO is active for that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it's doing a small string optimization (SSO). The loc_FIRST case would be the case where the string is contained in the SSO buffer, and just copies the 12 bytes of the string directly into the stack location for the string. The loc_THERE case is when SSO is inactive and calls std::string::__init to do the allocation and other non-SSO init work. So essentially that branch is part of the std::string construction which has been inlined into this code (but the slow non-SSO path is still out of line). The bit being checked presumably indicates whether SSO is active for that string. – BeeOnRope Mar 27 at 21:02